# How to execute FFMPEG using a compiled FFMPEG jar on Android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I added org.bytedeco.javacpp's ffmpeg-2.3-0-9.jar (https://www.versioneye.com/java/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:ffmpeg/2.3-0.9) and I need to be able to execute a command inside of my android app, such as:

```
    ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:15 -i in.mp4 -codec copy out.mp4
```

However, "ffmpeg" is not a class or a method that is exposed by this jar. Some posts suggest that I should be using the exec method when dealing with ffmpeg native code, but how do you do that (if that's even the right thing to do with this library)?
I am trying the following command without success.

```
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/libs/ffmpeg-2.3-0.9 -i -i in.mp4 -codec copy out.mp4");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check the tutorial on https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp-presets/tree/master/ffmpeg ?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately this tutorial only shows how to use the ffmpeg subclasses (avformat and avcodec), not ffmpeg itself. Any idea on how to do that? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use FFmpeg4Android. It is much more user friendly than anything out there that uses JNI, and it is able to accept ffmpeg commands within an AsyncTask. The imports are:

```
    import com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android.GeneralUtils;
    import com.netcompss.loader.LoadJNI;
```

The doInBackground code is:

```
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) Main.this.getSystemService(Activity.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "VK_LOCK");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    String commandStr = "ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:15 -i "+fullInVideoPath+" -codec copy " + fullOutVideoPath;
    LoadJNI vk = new LoadJNI();
    try {
    vk.run(GeneralUtils.utilConvertToComplex(commandStr), scishotfolder, getApplicationContext());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
    if (wakeLock.isHeld()) wakeLock.release();
    }
```

I hope this helps someone out there. The only problem is that it produces corrupted videos that cannot play inside of a VideoView! The other popular alternative called mp4parser also produces similarly corrupted mp4 files unfortunately.